# Node Modules and Prototype Inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, prototype

Currently I have:

index.js (in module foo)

```
function Foo(options) {
    this.memberVar = options.memberVar;
}

Foo.prototype.bar = function(word) {
    console.log('word: ', word);
}

module.exports = Foo;
```

server.js (in separate module bar)

```
var Foo = require('foo'),
    foo = new Foo(options),
    greeting = 'Hello World!';

foo.bar(greeting); // prints Hello World!
```

This is nice and all but I feel it could be prettier and easier for others to understand if I didn't have to use the new keyword to instantiate a new foo object to expose its member functions.

So here's what I would like to be able to do:

```
var greeting = 'Hello World!',
    foo = require('foo')(options);
foo.bar(greeting); // prints Hello World!
```

How do I modify my current foo - index.js to be able to access the Foo object as described in the code snippet above?

Comment: Your example is maybe misrepresenting your intentions, as it takes no use of context provided by OOP. If all your module provides are functions without the need for (per instance mutable) context, there is no need to pursue OOP.

Comment: Yeah I agree that I don't need to OOP in this example case, but this isn't my actual use case just some quick garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the consumers  of the module to use `new`, you can expose a factory method :

```
// index.js (in module foo)

function Foo(options) {
    this.memberVar = options.memberVar;
}

Foo.prototype.bar = function(word) {
    console.log('word: ', word);
}

module.exports = function(options) {
    return new Foo(options);
}


// server.js (in separate module bar) 

var greeting = 'Hello World!',
    foo = require('foo')(options);
foo.bar(greeting); // prints Hello World!
```

Please note, however, than it could **greatly** confuse the users of your module. Your original pattern is **widely accepted** and is the preferred way of exposing a constructor.